# 301 redirect from top-level domain to index.html in subdirectory

Tags: html, redirect, seo, indexing, multilingual

I am working on a small multi-language website. Originally, all of the html files were in the top level directory. Each page has an English version and a Spanish version, which are different html files. I would like to put these files in their own subdirectories, `en/` and `es/`, and then redirect the top-level domain to `en/index.html` (since English will be the default language).

But if I do this using a 301 redirect, won't search engines remove my top-level domain from their indexes? What I want is for users to enter `www.example.com` and arrive at `www.example.com/en/index.html`, but I still want `www.example.com` to show up in the SERPs.

I have no experience with Apache, so I don't know the correct approach for this. I read a little bit about 301 redirects, and it seemed like a possible way to do what I want, but I have no idea if it is the best way.

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Good question for webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: maybe take a look at multiviews?  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `302 Found` instead of `301 Moved Permanently`.